# read 300MB text file in C

Tags: c, file-io

What is the best way to read a text file (maximum size: 300 MB) in C? I want to search a specific pattern in a text file. Also, I have to access to all the text characters.

Comment: If you are on *nix, use sed. :)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to [mmap](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) the file into process space, and treat the file as it was a plain text string.   That will allow you avoid any complications with malloc memory allocation, fread etc and the OS will handle any paging in/out of data as needed.

The manual have a code example -- the essentials are below...

```
 int fd;
 struct stat sb;
 int filesize;
 char *filetext;
 fd = open("/path/to/my/300mb/file", O_RDONLY);
 if (fd == -1)
     handle_error("open");

 if (fstat(fd, &sb) == -1) /* To obtain file size */
     handle_error("fstat");
 filesize = sb.st_size;

 filetext = mmap(NULL, filesize, PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
 if (filetext == MAP_FAILED)
     handle_error("mmap");

  /* you now have the file mapped into memory with
     filetext[0] as the first byte and
     filetext[filesize-1] as the last byte
   */

  /* use the file content as a char* text string.... */
  while (....) do what ever needed

  /* release the file when done */
  munmap(filetext,filesize); 
  close(fd);
```

Comment: Thanks Soren. I think it will help me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If you have relatively unlimited memory (>>300MB), read the entire file into memory using fread() and use GNU regex library (http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html).

Comment: As much as machines have way more than 300MB of memory these days, what are the chances of `malloc` finding 300MB of *contiguous* memory?

Comment: @JimBuck Good point, depending on the OS, this could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `fread()`

`fread()` gives you as much control as `fgetc()`, and has the advantage of being able to read more than one character in a single I/O operation. In fact, memory permitting, you can read the entire file into an array and do all of your processing in memory. This has significant performance advantages.

Comment: It is good to read 300MB file and put it into an array. How can I define the array size when I don't know the exact size of the text file and the number of characters in it?

Comment: You would have to define a max file length and allocate an array with that length.